# No request from NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, networking

API doc states NSURLConnection::initWithRequest requests passed url argument. At server nothing is received however the argument is valid, and works from browser on same machine. What is going on in the rotten apple?

```
NSString* urlString = <valid url working from browser>;

NSURLRequest* request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval: 10];

NSURLConnection* connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

<Connection validated here>

<Delegate methods implemented elsewhere>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would try :

Is your urlString a valid URL? Just because it works in a browser doesn't mean it's a valid URL - the browser might be more tolerant that NSURL is. Test this by checking that the object created by `[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]` is not `nil`.

What does your `connection:didFailWithError:` delegate method return as the error parameter?

Does `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:` get called in your delegate - is it an authentication issue between your app and your server?

Are you retaining your `connection` object or is ARC releasing it (very unlikely, I'm pretty sure that the connection will hang around while it's connecting but you should probably make sure).

Answer (score 0):

It won't solve your problem, but increase the timeout to 60. Check the URL as the above answer says.

Comment: Have you _proved_ that the URL is correct or are you just assuming because the browser tells you it is? Can you add the URL to the question? And just because it's on the same LAN doesn't automatically mean that you can see the server :)

Comment: Hover to see actual url in statusbar: http://192.168.2.105:80/servlet/MyServletHandler?command=createsomething&unitid=1

Comment: OK, that's a pretty valid URL :) What about the other ideas in my answer - any luck?